# Separating Date and Time

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have a table displaying in my angular component and one of the columns is the date but it mashes the date and time together. I've tried separating them but I haven't had much luck doing so. the loop for placing each row of the csv data into my array obj is as follows:

```
let lines = csv.split("\n")
let headers = lines[0].split(/,/)
for(let i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
        let currLine = lines[i].split(",")
```

**then i try to manipulate the date element:**

I've tried to separate the the date column into different array pieces for each char then put them back together but when I try to separate the date string it throws an error.

`let jObj = currLine[1].split("")`

**ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')**

I've also tried to do the .replace("T", " ") so that way I could just split it by a " " but again it throws an error.

`let jObj = currLine[1].replace("T", " ")`

**ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')**

not sure if its a problem trying to separate an array element or my typescript coding. Can someone give me some suggestions please?

[image: Screenshot of table]

Comment: The error is saying `currLine[1]` is undefined. Check the length of your array and make sure what you are trying to access does exist. Do `console.log(currLine)` and share the results in your question.

Comment: Shouldn't the loop be `for(let i = 0; i < lines.length -1 ; i++) `

Comment: omg that was the problem...im sorry for wasting your time i didnt realize i was missing that. the -1 solved the error and split the line. thank you for that. if you want to put that into an answer ill gladly mark it correct.

Comment: No problem.  You can just mark the comment as useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, rather than worry about splitting the date and time whilst reading it in from the file, you could always use the Angular date pipe to format the datetime however you like.

https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Here are some examples on how you might see different date formats based on different parameters to the date pipe.

```
{{ dateObj | date }}               // output is 'Jun 15, 2015'
{{ dateObj | date:'medium' }}      // output is 'Jun 15, 2015, 9:43:11 PM'
{{ dateObj | date:'shortTime' }}   // output is '9:43 PM'
{{ dateObj | date:'mm:ss' }}       // output is '43:11'
```

Comment: Instead of just linking to the documentation, could you [edit] your answer to include additional details about this capability, such as a basic code example?